# How to detect whether "find" found any matches?

Tags: find, osx

Is there an idiomatic means to detect whether "find" found any matches? I'm currently using

```
COUNT=`find ... | wc -l`
if [ "$COUNT" -gt 0 ]; then
```

but this seems a little indirect to me. Also, I'd like find to stop searching once it's found a match, so it doesn't waste time and effort. I just need to know whether or not there are any files that match.

**Update:** I made the mistake of writing my question without the code in front of me: I use `wc -l` in a different case, where I need to know the total number of found files anyway. In the case where I'm only testing for whether there are any matches, I was using `if [ -z $(find …) ]`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you know you have GNU find, use [`-quit`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13860/how-to-detect-whether-find-found-any-matches/13862#13862)  to make it stop after the first match.

Portably, pipe the output of `find` into `head -n 1`. That way `find` will die of a broken pipe after a few matches (when it's filled `head`'s input buffer).

Either way, you don't need `wc` to test whether a string is empty, the shell can do it on its own.

```
if [ -n "$(find … | head -n 1)" ]; then …
```

Comment: Interesting... I thought `-n` only applied to 'defined' variables ($abc, $xyz, etc), but I suppose $(...) is a 'defined' temp variable.. +1  ... (and I just read recently that using `-n` is risky, unless you are sure that the variable has not already been declared and is 'unused)... but a temp won't have this possibility... ie. uninitialized vs. empty

Comment: @fred: On the contrary, `-n` tests whether a string is empty, it has nothing to do with variables. What you've read was probably saying that using `-n` doesn't test whether a variable is defined: `-n "$foo"` is false if `foo` is defined but empty, and displays an error message under `set -u`. `[ -n "${foo+1}" ]` reliably tests whether `foo` is set, but treating empty and unset variables identically is usually a good idea: `[ -n "${foo:+1}" ]`, or just `[ -n "$foo" ]` if you're not worried about `set -u`.

Comment: Thanks! I don't have `-quit` available, but piping to `head -n 1` works (as does `head -c 1`, which stops even earlier, but probably with negligible benefit). Also, I made the mistake of writing my question without the code in front of me: I use `wc -l` in a different case, where I need to know the total number of found files. In the case where I'm only testing for whether there are any matches, I was using `if [ -z \`find … \` ]`.

Comment: Just `head -1` also works.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`-quit`](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Directories.html#index-g_t_002dquit-49) action to stop after the first match.  You'll probably want to combine that with another action (like `-print`) or you won't be able to tell whether it found anything.

For example, `find ... -print -quit` will print the path of the first matching file and then exit.  Or, you could use `-printf 1 -quit` to print 1 if there's a match and nothing if there isn't.

`find`'s exit status reflects whether there were errors while searching, and not whether it found anything, so you have to check its output to see if there's a match.

Comment: `-quit` is a GNU extension. It won't work on systems using other implementations of find(1), such as OS X, the BSDs, and probably most commercial Unices.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful to know in case I'm using another system. Unfortunately, neither -quit nor -printf are available on mine (Mac OS X).

Answer (score 4):

Exit 0 is easy with find, exit >0 is harder because that usually only happens
with an error. However we can make it happen:

```sh
if find -type f -exec false {} +
then
  echo 'nothing found'
else
  echo 'something found'
fi
```

Note that this solution is more performant than using a subshell; execing false
is certainly faster than execing even Dash:

```sh
$ cat alfa.sh bravo.sh charlie.sh delta.sh
find -name non-existing-file -exec false {} +
find -name existing-file -exec false {} +
[ "$(find -name non-existing-file)" ]
[ "$(find -name existing-file)" ]

$ strace dash alfa.sh | wc -l
807

$ strace dash bravo.sh | wc -l
1141

$ strace dash charlie.sh | wc -l
1184

$ strace dash delta.sh | wc -l
1194
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it into the shell condition, e.g.:

```
[ "$(find . ...)" '!=' '' ] && echo Found || echo Not found
```

Where `...` is your match condition, e.g. `-name *.txt`.

Some other examples:

```
[ "$(find /etc -name hosts)" ] && echo True || echo False
[ ! -z "$(find /etc -name hosts)" ] && echo True || echo False
```